# How to delete Crisp Chat plugin completely?

Tags: plugins, uninstallation

I had installed a chat plugin called Crisp chat. But i still see crisp chat box in my mobile but not in PC. I have deleted it yet it is seen in mobile. please guide me.

Comment: You will need to ask it’s author. Third party plugins are off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed it from your hosting provider? Navigate to the wp-content/plugins folder where your website is hosted and delete it from there. And also clear the cache of any cache plugins you may have.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to a caching issue from a plugin or at server/host level.
If you have a caching plugin installed, try deleting the cache.